# Is it possible to restrict fit/fdescribe functions by JSCS/JSHint?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am working in some development team. We have unit tests in our programm. There are many tests in it. Each test covers one module. In common, one developer is working only on one or some modules (but not many) per one task. To improve unit tests speed I use focused specs (I use Jasmine and our app is AngularJS app).

The problem: sometimes I forget to remove focused specs. I commit and PR with `fit`/`fdescribe` calls in programm. It can cause problems for me and other developers in the future. Obvious example: developer is developing :), he made a mistake, he started tests and only focused specs worked, since he worked on another file - it is a problem - there will be mistake but he wouldn't see it.

Is there any methods to automatically find focused specs in my tests and warn developer about it? Our team is using CI with grunt running on it. Grunt has tasks for jscs and jshint. Maybe it is somehow possible to create own rules to prevent this mistake?

Answer (score 2):

I would setup a git hook and utilise [grunt-ddescribe-iit](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ddescribe-iit).

For now, let's use [grunt-githooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks) to setup the git hook.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  githooks: {    
    options: {
      'pre-push': 'grunt ddescribe-iit'
    }
  },
  ddescribe-iit: {
    files: [
      'test/**/*.js',
      'app/**/*.spec.js'
    ]
  }
});
```

---

That's a very contrived example of how *I imagine it would work*, I haven't utilised ddescribe-iit myself (though, like you - I should be!) nor have I used grunt-githooks.

Looking through how they're both put together however, my established guess is that this would be a *fairly painless* process to set up.

Like you, we are also utilising a CI system and it has **always** been a pain when a build passes, but it only ran a couple of chosen tests. Using a git hook that screams in your face before pushing, kills the problem at the root I reckon (without introducing watchers and additional processes during the development step).

All at the amazing cost of development overhead of **0**.

---

**edit:** this answer assumes that you are utilising grunt as a task runner. there are [equivalents](https://github.com/caitp/gulp-ddescribe-iit) [for](https://github.com/therealklanni/git-guppy) gulp.